# Upgraded to Flutter 3.7. M1 mac - have Pod Install Issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I upgraded flutter via flutter upgrade to 3.7. And now im getting the following issue when I flutter build macos my application.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 9.3.0, ~> 9.3.0)
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/macos`) was resolved to 3.11.2, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 9.6.0)
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.
```

I have tried every suggestion such as

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install

arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

Deleting Podfiles.

Deleting PodLock.

Has someone else come across the same issue and have a resolution for me by any chance?

To be able to flutter clean and build my application with flutter 3.7

Comment: 1st check your team in xcode & check for debug,release,profile team are same or not then try again

Comment: Checked. Debug, release and profile have no configuration set.

Comment: Issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: It was to do with the version of Firebase, seemed to be conflicting issues with version and depednecies. In the Podspec replace each firebase related item as follows:
firebase_core: ^1.20.1
TO
firebase_core: 1.20.1